# How to create custom input component with validation in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, controlvalueaccessor, angular-controlvalueaccessor

I want to create custom component for input text but I don't know how can I bind validation of each input field to custom component. Is there any way to set errors of each field as array of objects like below

```
<app-custom-input
          formControlName="username"
          label="Username"
          [errors]="[
          { type: 'required', message: 'is required' },
          { type: 'minlength', message: 'min length error' }
        ]"
        ></app-custom-input>
```

[stackblitz.io](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-custom-input-controlvalueaccessor-yyincy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You did most of the stuff already. The only missing thing is to correctly implement to your needs the `validate` function inside the custom component.

```
private readonly minLength = 3;

public validate(c: FormControl) {
    const errors: ValidationErrors[] = [];

    if (!c.value) {
      errors.push({error: "REQUIRED"});
    }

    if(c.value?.length < this.minLength) {
      errors.push({error: "MINLENGTH", minLength: this.minLength});
    }

    // Other validation logics...

    return errors;
}
```

Angular will take care of validating the control when the return array has length 0, while you can format the `ValidationErrors` shape to your needs.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-custom-input-controlvalueaccessor-g6jwsb?file=src/app/custom-input/custom-input.component.ts) is your code updated, with the current `control.error` and validity displayed below the input.

Sidenote: It would be nice to reference a `ValidatorFn` to validate the code instead of checking the control value itself, but unfortunately I was not able to do that.

Comment: Thank you
But unfortunately, the link sent does not open, is it possible to fix it?

Comment: thank you, But my main question is, how can I give the error messages as a property to the custom input  like:     <app-custom-input
              formControlName="username"
              label="Username"
              [errors]="[
              { type: 'required', message: ' is required ' },
              { type: 'minlength', message: ' min length error   ' }
            ]"
            ></app-custom-input>

Comment: I have edited the Stackblitz link to exactly what I want